# Proof by cases if are given $P$ or $Q$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

My proof writing book (*How to Prove It*) states that when I am given a statement of the form $P \lor Q$, I can break the proof into cases where I first assume $P$ is true, and then assume $Q$ is true. Why can I not assume $P$ to be false in the second case? Because: $P\lor Q \iff (P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q) \lor (P \land Q)$. Hence, if I manage to prove whatever I am proving by assuming $P$ is true, the only other case I would need to consider is $\neg P \land Q$, or am I confused?

Comment: Not very clear... If the assumption of the proof is of form $P \lor Q$, we have to split it into two sub-cases: (i) prove the result (call it $R$) under the assumption $P$, (ii) prove the result $R$ under the assumption $Q$, and finally conclude using the [Proof by cases rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).  The result is a proof of $R$ (under assumption $P \lor Q$).

Comment: What isn't clear? Why can't I assume in (ii) that $P$ is false?

Comment: Because it is not necessary: what we have to assume is the truth of $Q$. A different case if we want to prove a *claim* of form $P \lor Q$. In this second case we can use the strategy: either (i) prove $P$, or (ii) assume $P$ false and prove $Q$.

Comment: I think I understand. My mistake was that I thought when assuming $P$, because we don't assume anything about $Q$, $Q$ can be true or false (which isn't the case). Thank you.

Comment: We do not even need the subcase that $P$ is true because in this case , there is nothing to prove. You can immediately assume that $P$ is false and for the proof of $Q$, you can use this assumption. Maybe , it is easier to assume that $Q$ is false and to prove $P$. This depends on what exactly has to be proven.

Comment: Hint: To prove $P\lor Q \implies \cdots$, consider 2 cases: $P$ or $Q$. Within case 1 ($P$), consider 2 sub-cases: $Q$ or $\neg Q.$ Within case 2 ($Q$), consider 2 sub-cases: $P$ or $\neg P$. To prove the converse, consider 3 cases: $P\land \neg Q$ or $\neg P \land Q$ or $P \land Q$.

Comment: ... The full proof consists of 51 lines of formal proof using a form of natural deduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $P\lor Q \Leftrightarrow (P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land Q) \lor (P \land Q)$, we can do several things:

1. We can break it up into *three* cases: one where we assume $P \land \neg Q$, a second where we assume $\neg P \land Q$, and a third where we assume $P \land Q$.  The advantage of doing this is that in each case we immediately get two smaller statements to work with (e.g. from the assumption of $P \land Q$ you can quickly infer both $P$ and $Q$), and you can often combine those smaller statements with other statements you already have to continue with the proof and get to what you want. Of course, the disadvantage is that you have to consider three cases instead of two, so that could mean more work.
2. We can do what you suggest: have one case that assumes $P$ and a second case where you assume $\neg P \land Q$.  And yes, that totally works as well: the $P$ case covers both the more specific case of $P \land Q$ as well as the case that $P \land \neg Q$, and so again all possible cases are covered.  This method is a little 'ugly' or 'awkward' though: you now have one case where you assume a simple statement $P$ and a second where you assume a much more complex statement $\neg P \land Q$ ... that feels strangely assymmetrical or unbalanced or something. Indeed, following this method you could just as well assume $Q$ as one case, and $\neg Q \land P$ as a second ... would one way of splitting into cases be considered to follow the formal rule but the other not?  It would make sense that both ways would be ok, but now it becomes ugly in the very fact *that* you have choices in which to split into cases .. that kind of increased cognitive load makes proofs harder to construct and follow. So yes, you can do what you suggest .. but it's not pretty.
3. You can have $P$ as one case and $Q$ as another case. As with the above, the $P$ case covers both the $P \land Q$ as well as the case that $P \land \neg Q$.  On the other hand, the $Q$ case covers both $P \land Q$ and $\neg P \land Q$ cases.  Hmm, so the $P \land Q$ case is covered twice. Is that a problem?  No!  As long as all possible cases are covered, you're good. And the fact that the $P \land Q$ is covered twice is only implicitly so: it doesn't create more work. Indeed, just have a simple $P$ case and a simple $Q$ case makes this method probably the most efficient ... and also the most *intuitive*: If you have $P \lor Q$, then it makes sense to consider the cases of $P$ and $Q$: the disjunction *directly* translates into all the cases you need!  So this is what pretty much every book and proof system does.

Comment: This is exactly what I wasn't sure about, thank you. Just a quick question, in 2., if we assume $P$, it only covers $P\land Q$ and $P\land\neg Q$ iff we don't make any assumption regarding $Q$ during the proof, right?

Comment: @Wernher Yes, exactly. :)